# Why am I getting the exception "Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types"

Tags: c#, wcf, nhibernate, datacontractserializer, castle-activerecord

I'm trying to serialise a object to Xml using the DataContractSerializer.  I have the following classes;

```
[ActiveRecord(Lazy = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(RoomType))]
[DataContract]
public class Room : ActiveRecordBase<Room>
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Int64 RoomId { get; protected set; }

    [BelongsTo("RoomTypeId")]
    [DataMember]
    public virtual RoomType RoomType { get; set; }

    [Property]
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Int64 HotelId { get; set; }

    [Property]
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [Property]
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public static Room[] FindByHotelId(Int64 HotelId)
    {
        return (Room[])FindAllByProperty(typeof(Room), "HotelId", HotelId);
    }
}
```

The RoomType class is

```
[ActiveRecord(Lazy = true)]
[DataContract]
public class RoomType : ActiveRecordBase<RoomType>
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [DataMember]
    public virtual int RoomTypeId { get; protected set; }

    [Property]
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

}
```

I use the following method to serialise the object

```
    internal static XElement ObjectToXElement<T>(T source)
    {
        XDocument oXDocument = new XDocument();

        try
        {
            using (var writer = oXDocument.CreateWriter())
            {
                // write xml into the writer
                var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(source.GetType());
                serializer.WriteObject(writer, source);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            using (var writer = oXDocument.CreateWriter())
            {
                // write xml into the writer
                var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(oError.GetType());
                serializer.WriteObject(writer, oError);
            }
        }

        return oXDocument.Root;
    }
```

The actual object I'm serialising is;

```
[KnownType(typeof(List<Room>))]
[KnownType(typeof(RoomType))]
[DataContract]
public class RoomTypeResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Code { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }

    public RoomTypeResponse()
    {
        this.Rooms = new List<Room>();
    }
}
```

But for some reason when I call the method to serialise the object I get the following exception;

> Type 'Castle.Proxies.RoomTypeProxy' with data contract name
>   'RoomTypeProxy:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Castle.Proxies'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any
>   types not known statically to the list of known types - for example,
>   by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the
>   list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

If I comment out the property in Room class, it works fine

```
[BelongsTo("RoomTypeId")]
[DataMember]
public virtual RoomType RoomType { get; set; }
```

I'm not sure why I am getting the exception, because I've added the knowtype attribute for RoomType ?  What am I missing, that is causing this problem.

Comment: No resolution for you on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that one type (Castle.Proxies.RoomTypeProxy) is generated at runtime, so .NET knows nothing about it. This is not an NHibernate-specific problem. If you disable lazy loading and proxy generation, the problem will go away, but I understand it might be difficult.
Other option would be to use another serializer, like BinaryFormatter, but I don't know if that will work for you.